# Android APK control flow graph with soot

Tags: java, android, control-flow-graph, soot

I'm trying to make a control flow graph with the soot API from an Android APK. I have read a lot but i feel a little bit helpless how to start from scratch. I'm using a nighty build of soot (downloaded here: https://ssebuild.cased.de/nightly/soot/lib/) because I read that version 2.5.0 is outdated. I found a lot with google, for example:

https://mailman.cs.mcgill.ca/pipermail/soot-list/2014-September/007303.html

First I need to load the Android APK file. On the link it's done with:

```
SetupApplication app = new SetupApplication(...)
```

But thats already the first problem, there is no *SetupApplication* in the nightly build soot.jar.

I did it with the command line, like here:

http://www.abartel.net/dexpler/

that worked almost, but building the control flow graph is only the first step. After that I have to manipulate the graphs and use it as an input for some other framework. So command line is no option for me. I would prefer to do it with Java!

Can someone help a soot newbie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting call graph through Soot, try the Soot lib located at https://github.com/secure-software-engineering/soot-infoflow-android instead. 
Then import soot.jimple.infoflow.android.SetupApplication in your Java source code.
Everything should be fine.

Comment: He asked for a control flow graph, not a call graph

Comment: @Pbasak  a call graph is a inter-procedure control flow graph. I do not think the generation of intra-procedure cfg bothers him since extracting them is nothing special.